# Parasite? or a possible home infestation?

Tags: entomology

[image]

I found this bug on my bed tonight.  It's smaller than a sesame seed. 6 legs and 2 antenna.

Is this causing my dog and I to itch? Should I be concerned?

Answer (score 2):

It is a minute pirate bug, in the family Anthocoridae. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anthocoridae They are generally thought to be beneficial insects, in that they are predators of pests. Do you have some house plants that may be infested with something else they are feeding on (like aphids)? Unfortunately, minute pirate bugs do bite, and the bite is painful. https://hortnews.extension.iastate.edu/2017/10/minute-pirate-bugs-are-biting-argh
But these are not human parasites, and I would not be concerned. Just find what they are feeding on, and take care of that.